# `scrapy` can't get response from a website but `requests` can

Tags: web-scraping, python-requests, scrapy, web-crawler

I am using `scrapy` to crawl [this](https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/) page

but for some reason `scrapy` cannot receive a response from this website.
when i run the crawler I receive https 500 error

here is my basic `spider`

```py
import scrapy

class SavingsGov(scrapy.Spider):
    name        = 'savings'
    start_urls  = [
        'https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for option in response.css('select option'):
            yield {
                'url': option.css('::attr(value)').get()
            }
```

and here are the errors I get when I run it, (I have also increased the number of retries to 10 in `settings.py`)

```
2023-08-26 16:30:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-08-26 16:30:22 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-08-26 16:30:22 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-08-26 16:30:24 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:25 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:27 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:28 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 4 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:30 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 5 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:31 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 6 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:33 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 7 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:35 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 8 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:37 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 9 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:39 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 10 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:40 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (failed 11 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:40 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET https://savings.gov.pk/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2023-08-26 16:30:40 [protego] DEBUG: Rule at line 1 without any user agent to enforce it on.
2023-08-26 16:30:41 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 1 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:43 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 2 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:44 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:46 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 4 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:47 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 5 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 6 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:50 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 7 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:52 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 8 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:53 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 9 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:55 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 10 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:56 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] ERROR: Gave up retrying <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (failed 11 times): 500 Internal Server Error
2023-08-26 16:30:56 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/> (referer: None)
2023-08-26 16:30:56 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <500 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-08-26 16:30:56 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

but I can easily get a response using python's `requests` module.
here is the python code for that

```py
import requests

response = requests.get('https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/')
print(response.text)
```

I don't know why this is happening, I am assuming that the problem is with `scrapy.Request`.

is there any way to perform requests with `requests` and pass the response to `scrapy`? but the preferable option would be to somehow debug `scrapy.Request`

I am new to `scrapy` so if there is a possibility that I'm misunderstanding the problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is most likely because the server probably rejects requests from scrapy default user agent.

Try setting a custom one in the spiders custom settings. Also set ROBOTSTXT_OBEY to false.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class SavingsGov(scrapy.Spider):
    name        = 'savings'
    start_urls  = [
        'https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/'
    ]
    custom_settings = {
        "USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
        "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for option in response.css('select option'):
            yield {
                'url': option.css('::attr(value)').get()
            }
```

Partial output:

```
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-1500-draw-list/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-200-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-1500-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-25000-premium-bonds-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-15000-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-40000-premium-bonds-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-40000-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-25000-draws/'}
2023-08-26 21:11:24 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://savings.gov.pk/download-draws/>
{'url': 'http://savings.gov.pk/rs-7500-draws/'}
```

Comment: Thank you, It worked. changing only the `USER_AGENT` worked as well too